# Mysql loop errors

Tags: mysql, syntax, syntax-error

I have a syntax error with my code, which adds 1000 random records to a table.\

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addrecords()
BEGIN
  DECLARE a INT Default 1;
  my_loop: LOOP 
    <INSERTING>
    SET a = a + 1;
    IF a=1001 THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;
  END LOOP my_loop;
END
```

first syntax error is at default 1 saying it's missing a semicolon, then at my_loop and there are like 4 more.. Any help please? It seems good to go from what I've gooogled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter before defining the statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE addrecords()
BEGIN
  DECLARE a INT Default 1;
  my_loop: LOOP 
    <INSERTING>
    SET a = a + 1;
    IF a=1001 THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;
  END LOOP my_loop;
END

$$
```

Otherwise, the `;` will end the entire `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.